# File_get_contents to get the source code of remote page then display only specific div

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

exactly as its descriped in the title currently my code is:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://www.vipboxsports.me/football/23863/1/chelsea-tv-live-stream-online.html";
    $html = str_get_html($url);
    $elem = $html->find('div[id=streambox]', 0);
    echo $elem;
?>
```

but at this point its not working what is the problem with code above

Comment: This code snippet refers to a URL, but never actully reads the page.

Comment: it should be echo $elem;

Comment: post your real code, we can't go by this pseudo code you have provided.

Comment: you can use **file_get_content()** function to get all content of site then use **explode()** function to find your specific div.

Comment: @DevZer0 i have edit the code in question check it

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `file_get_html`. `str_get_html` is when you have a string of html already.

```
$url = "http://www.vipboxsports.me/football/23863/1/chelsea-tv-live-stream-online.html";
$html = file_get_html($url);
$elem = $html->find('div[id=streambox]', 0);
echo $elem;
```

Comment: is `simplehtmldom` installed on your server?

Comment: you mean that i should include it in the file with include function?

Comment: i am testing on local host with wamp

Comment: do you have it included in your file

Comment: also check the error log, php error log or apache error log it gives you more information regarding the error

Comment: fiddle don't allow `file_put_contents`. so i can't show you but you should check if your php setting `allow_fopen_url = 1` for starters

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $url = "remotesite.com/pages/page1.html";
    $html = str_get_html($url);
    $elem = $html->find('div[id=mydiv]', 0);
    echo $elem;
?>
```